# NLP Methodology in Python to find 3-Character Common Combinations

Tags: python, nlp, probability

I have a real-world meets math world problem.  I'm creating cupcake molds that are 3x4 cavity to a mold.  Each mold cost $1,000 to make.

I have a set of characters A-Z (26) and I need to find an efficient combination of 3 letters.

ie., 
Option 1) Create 26 molds where each mold has a single character
Option 2) Create 13 molds where each mold has two characters
(i.e., 3x2 for A, 3x2 for B in an AB-mold)
Option 3) Create n molds where each mold has three characters

ie., based on tokenization of 3-letter combinations in the english language, is there a solution for common 3-letter pairing that each letter is at least represented once and the total mold count is <13 (option 2)

http://www.rollingr.net/wordpress/2007/02/02/common-letter-sequence/

For example, for Option 3) I would imagine there would be a single mold for 'ING' but perhaps also one for 'ION'

Is there a minimum number of trigraphs that would cover the entire alphabet?

Comment: I don't understand why you make the distinction between the unigram, bigram, and trigram molds

Comment: I guess I don' need to make a distinction and perhaps this question is a bit esoteric.  I'm trying to find the minimum for the different types of cupcake molds I need to optimize for the cost of tooling vs. the time it takes for me to make the most useful combinations of words.  The molds can also contain 1, 2 or 3 letter combinations. If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency you can see that perhaps 'E' warrants its own mold but you can combine Z, Q, X, J into a bigram or trigram.